# How can i build for iPadOS 15.7 under XCode Version 14.0 (14A309)

Tags: xcode, ios16, ipados

Apple released the stable XCode, with an unreleased iPadOS16... there was nowhere the mention the iPadOS16 is a beta

so when i tried to submit the app i got rejected for using the iPadOS16 as beta software

How can i build for iPadOS 15.7 under XCode Version 14.0 (14A309)?

Comment: Did you download Xcode 14.0.1? The note is "This update fixes an issue that prevents development with devices running iOS 5.7." Not sure if this fixes the issue - I am arguing with Apple right now trying to get an answer.